# Colocar números nas linhas de código

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Não sei se é aqui que postamos melhorias, mas hoje precisei falar sobre um trecho do código do AP e notei que ele terá que ler meu trecho e sair procurando no meio do monte de código dele essa linha.

Teria como implementar nos trechos dos código fontes no inicio de cada linha o numero da linha correspondente?

Comment: Acho que isso não foi implementado propositalmente, como explicado no SOen [aqui](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings). Basicamente, espera-se que os blocos de código sejam pequenos *snippets*, e números de linhas poderiam causar confusão uma vez que o código fosse editado e a numeração fosse modificada, o que é relativamente comum no SO já que as perguntas e respostas são atualizadas com frequência.

Comment: Relacionado: [Numeração de linhas em códigos grandes](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1777/3117)